# Change color of link buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to change the color of my button text to white, the buttons which show who is logged in and the logout button. Right now its blue and not easy to see whats it shows.

I think it's because the buttons are links, that why its blue.

[image]

Code:

```
  <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  
<span class="label label-info" style="color:white">  Innlogget:  <a class="navbar-link" style="color:white">{{ HTML::linkRoute('user_data', Auth::user()->user_name) }} </a> </span> |
<span class="label label-danger" style="color:white">{{ HTML::linkRoute('logout', 'Logg ut') }} </span></p> 
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
```

Comment: .label a{color:#fff} should work

Comment: Superb! Another question, is it possible to create a space between them without using a |  ?

Comment: Yeah buddy! Just use a margin in your CSS.

`.label {margin-left:10px;}`

Comment: yes probably you should post jsfiddle or html and css markup for better answer. you can try .label-info:after {
  content: "|"; margin-left:8px;
}

Comment: Last question, make the text size bigger in both bottoms and the Innlogget text?

Comment: .label, .label a{font-size:18px;} please make sure that these classes solutions are given as per provided markup they may affect all css wherever same classes aer used

Comment: @PravinVaichal Why don't you fine fellas do all this in an answer so that other visitors can benefit and you get the answer credit you deserve ;)

Comment: @LOTUSMS thanks but I was not sure as markup was not completely provided so I thought I should give hint first

Comment: To echo LOTUSMS, gather all this info you've provided and put it in an answer. People will find it more easily in the future, and you can get some deserved points.

Comment: @AndyM thats right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.label, 
.label a{font-size:18px; /*change font size as per requirement*/ color:#fff} 

.label-info:after { content: "|"; margin-left:8px; }
```

should work

Comment: As you mentioned, how will the best way to put it in the classes? So it doesn't affect all css wherver same class are used? –

Comment: well what you can do is you can wrap a div e.g. <div class="user-action"> ..your all markup ..</div> and then you can do as .user-action .label, .user-action .label a {font-size:18px;} so this wont affect anywhere unless you define same class i.e.user-action

Answer (score 1):

**CSS** Not proven

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link, a:visited {
color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
........
</body>
```

You say link then this is if its just only a link.